# How to center two sibling TextView in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have layout like below. Need that `b` and `c` will be centered below `a`. To simplify view need only this **one RelativeLayout** if is possible.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test 1"
        android:paddingTop="3dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_below="@id/a"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="test 2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/b"
        android:layout_below="@id/a"
        android:textColor="#f00"
        android:text="test 3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE**
Now i ended with something like below, but it is not the best, because `b` and `c` are not exactly below `a`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test 1"
        android:paddingTop="3dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="test 2"
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/b"
        android:textColor="#f00"
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:text="test 3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you upload a picture with end effect you want to achieve? `b` and `c` below `a` says nothing about `b` and `c` are not staggered on each other or they are laying beside them and then  they are aligned to the center.

Answer (score 1):

you have to wrap them in another layout, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test 1"
        android:paddingTop="3dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/a"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/b"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="test 2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/c"
            android:textColor="#f00"
            android:text="test 3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have not mention that need only one RelativeLayout to simplify View

Comment: you can't do like this. You NEED TO wrap in another layout

Comment: I had something like You propose, but this is a part of item layout in huge ListView and need to simplify that for performance. You sure that is not possible in single RelativeLayout ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. `RelativeLayout` does not provide any means of making centered elements side by side. You center a container and put them inside the container. You must try to simplify your `ListView` somewhere else, better handle `getView` update, properly recycle the views, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
`<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test 1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:paddingTop="3dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/a">

    <TextView
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="test 2"
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/b"
        android:layout_below="@id/a"
        android:textColor="#f00"
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:text="test 3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: for not explaining anything and only posting wall of code

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#dd80aa"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="This is on the top"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Maybe I will try to make this a long text"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginRight="88dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="#aa80ee"
    android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="This time I'll try to do this on the right side"
    android:padding="20dp" android:background="#70aa80"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="88dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="88dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

for situations like this I use View. This works perfect for me

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test 1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="3dp" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/center_view"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/a"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_below="@id/a"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center_view"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="test 2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center_view"
        android:layout_below="@id/a"
        android:textColor="#f00"
        android:text="test 3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible you need to use two viewgroup layout either you have to use linearlayout inside Relativelatyou or RelativeLayout inside RelativeLayout

You can only do like this if you use only one ReltiveLayout[image: singleRelativelayout]

Answer (score 0):

Textview a is not in center of the relativelayout. Add android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  for textview a.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="60dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="test 1"
    android:paddingTop="3dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:layout_below="@id/a"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:text="test 2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/c"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/b"
    android:layout_below="@id/a"
    android:textColor="#f00"
    android:text="test 3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
**Try this**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtView1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="TextView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtView2"
        android:text="TextView3" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```